# Select lines between "*line1*" and "*line2*"

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, grep

How can I use grep to select lines from **line1** to **line2** in some text?

Comment: What are your problems? be especific please...

Comment: I'm downloading html pages and i want to output image links that the code contains... there for i need to search from string "http://" to "jpg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we have some text

```
$> cat ./text
text
some text
string1
some text again
and that
string2
done
this should not be printed
```

And we want to get the lines between **string1** and **string2**. So `awk` is the best tool that might be used there.

```
$> cat ./btw
/string1/ { printing = 1 }
/string2/ { print $0; printing = 0 }
printing  { print $0 }
```

Usage:

```
$> awk -f ./btw ./text
string1
some text again
and that
string2
```

Comment: Actually, sed would be a little simpler for this, if that's what he's asking for: `sed -n '/string1/,/string2/p'`

Comment: Dan Fego, it's awesome, didn't know about that!

Comment: sed -n '/http/,/jpg/p' wget.html gives me the whole page

Answer (score 1):

Use sed (split onto two lines for clarity).

```
echo "grep is a command-line text-search utility originally written for Unix." \
| sed -n 's/.*\(utility originally written\).*/\1/p'
```

What this does:

- The `-n` argument suppresses printing of all lines.
- The `s` command at the beginning begins a substitution expression.
- The part between the first `/` and the second `/` describes what you want to find.

  - `.*` means "anything"
  - `\(utility originally written\)` is what you're looking for, in between two escaped parentheses, saying that this is an expression we can back-reference later.
  - `.*` again means "anything"
- The part between the second `/` and third `/` is the replacement expression.

  - The `\1` says "use the first expression in parentheses from the first part"
- The final `p` says "print out matching substitutions."

**Edit:** For reference, the original question (for some reason it doesn't show any edits) was below. For the life of me I don't know why he made it worse and less specific.

> How can I use grep to find text from line to line
>
> lets say I want to grep only "utility originally written" from the
>   following text. How can i do that? Please help
>
> grep is a command-line text-search utility originally written for
>   Unix.

Comment: I need command that can search from utility to written

Comment: You shouldn't be down-voting an answer to a question which is as vague as yours. Read FAQ on how to ask questions.

Comment: i can't vote at all. what are youtaling abou?!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-o option` of `grep` utility. Something like this -

```
-o, --only-matching
              Show only the part of a matching line that matches PATTERN.

[jaypal:~] echo "grep is a command-line text-search utility originally written\
for Unix."| grep -o "utility originally written"
utility originally written
[jaypal:~]
```

Comment: and how can i search from utility to written? and show everything that is between

Comment: What do you mean by **utility to written**?

Comment: I want to grep an image link from html files, i only need the link without all the html code around.